# Tensorflow Layers (Keras) Conv2d - How to train for single output (regression)

Tags: keras, regression, conv-neural-network, tensorflow.js

I'm new to Keras and CNNs and am trying to train a CNN for regression but I can't seem to figure out how to build a model for a single output (regression). When using a regular ANN (using a normal `dense` layer instead of `conv2d`) I can simply set the last dense layer to have one unit and this gives one output (and the target can be a 1d tensor). However, in the following model the output shape must be the same as the input shape. What am I missing?

This model is a dumbed-down version of what I'm actually trying to do, but describes my issue well.

*This is tensorflow js but for the most part reads the same as python.

```
    const model = tf.sequential()
    model.add(
      tf.layers.conv2d({
        inputShape: [3, 3, 1],
        filters: 1,
        kernelSize: [2, 2]
      })
    )

    // I thought the last dense layer was what determines
    // the number of outputs
    model.add(
      tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, activation: 'linear'})
    )

    model.compile({
      optimizer: tf.train.sgd(0.001),
      loss: tf.losses.meanSquaredError
    })

    const train = tf.tensor4d([
      [
        [[0], [0], [0]],
        [[0], [0], [0]],
        [[0], [0], [0]]
      ],
      [
        [[0], [0], [0]],
        [[0], [0], [0]],
        [[0], [0], [0]]
      ],
      [
        [[0], [0], [0]],
        [[0], [0], [0]],
        [[0], [0], [0]]
      ],
      [
        [[0], [0], [0]],
        [[0], [0], [0]],
        [[0], [0], [0]]
      ]
    ])

    // Why must the target be this shape?
    const target = tf.tensor4d([
      [[[0], [0]], [[0], [0]]],
      [[[0], [0]], [[0], [0]]],
      [[[0], [0]], [[0], [0]]],
      [[[0], [0]], [[0], [0]]],
    ])

    model.fit(train, target)

    const predict = tf.tensor4d([
      [
        [[0], [0], [0]],
        [[0], [0], [0]],
        [[0], [0], [0]]
      ]
    ])

    const prediction = model.predict(predict) as tf.Tensor
    prediction.print()
```

I must be missing something simple - still can't find the answer anywhere. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Just need to flatten the output of the convolutional layer:

```
model.add(tf.layers.flatten())
```

After the convolutional layer will do it.